# Nginx redirect sending localhost instead of the server_name ip adress

Tags: nginx, centos

I'm getting a problem with my nginx configuration running on CentOS 7.
I'm trying to send the http request on port 80  to a ssl port on 443 the two servers a set up like below:

```
upstream backend {
    server 192.168.1.79:8080;
}
    server {
         listen   80;
        #listen   [::]:80;
        server_name TOTO02; #192.168.1.78

        rewrite ^ https://CERVO02$request_uri;
    }

    server {

        listen 443 ssl spdy;
        server_name  TOTO02;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

        #charset koi8-r;
        #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;    


        location / {
            #root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            #index  index.html index.htm;

           proxy_pass http://backend;# backend c'est pas une variable 

            proxy_cache my-test-cache;
            proxy_cache_valid  200 302  60m;
            proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;
            proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout invalid_header updating;
            proxy_redirect default;
        }
```

The problem i'm having is that the url i'm getting back form the http server is `https://localhost/` And the thing is that the host file are all set corectly on both server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what it was the problem was with the browser i was using chrome that had the previous error but because of caching by the browser it  keept the old error. Once i tested it with Internet Explorer with it work whit no error.